# month value always prints wrong

Tags: javascript

I am getting a string like `"Mar, 2016"`. I would like to find the `month` in `number`. I get weird/error results.

```
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun","Jul",
                 "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

new Date(str.split(", ")[1], months.indexOf(str.split(", ")[0]) + 1, new Date().getDate());
```

Why does the above code print me... `April` instead of `March`.

```
Fri Apr 01 2016 00:00:00
```

Comment: JavaScript months are zero-based indexes, so March is month 2 and April is month 3

Comment: Because your array index starts with a `[0]` not a `[1]`

Answer (score 2):

`months.indexOf(str.split(", ")[0]) + 1` is incorrect. Months are 0-indexed. Leave it as `months.indexOf(str.split(", ")[0])`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are adding 1 to it

```
new Date(str.split(", ")[1], months.indexOf(str.split(", ")[0]) + 1, new Date().getDate());
```

remove it

`new Date(str.split(", ")[1], months.indexOf(str.split(", ")[0]), new Date().getDate());`

and you will be fine